# C-parity violation evidence

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, cp-violation, cpt-symmetry, charge-conjugation

I know about the CP-violation experiments from the 60's and the P-violation from the 50's. But, is there a similar experiment which displays (perhaps historically in the same way as the experiements of Wu and Christensen) the violation of Charge conjugation alone?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316057/44126

Answer (score 6):

There is not, because the combined transformation $CPT$ is a symmetry of all Lorentz-invariant systems.  The $P$-violating decay distribution observed by [Wu et al.](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.105.1413) is also a $C$-violating distribution, because polarized anti-cobalt would have had the opposite sign of asymmetry.  (However no one has ever made, or probably will ever make, polarized anti-cobalt, so that particular claim is unverified.)

The [Garwin, Lederman, and Weinrich experiment](http://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.105.1415) published simultaneously with Wu's result measured opposite polarizations for $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ produced from unpolarized pions.  (Pions are spinless, and therefore unpolarizable.)  The *existence* of the polarization is a $P$-violation; the correlation of polarization with charge is a $C$-violation; the pion-producing decays separately conserve $CP$ and $T$, to conserve $CPT$.

Conservation of $CP$ is an automatic consequence of a weak interaction with only two generations of isospin doublets; three generations are necessary for the [CKM matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabibbo%E2%80%93Kobayashi%E2%80%93Maskawa_matrix) to carry a $CP$-violating phase.  We have experimental evidence that $CP$-violating phases in our universe are small, but the [Sakharov conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#Sakharov_conditions) tell us that the evolution of the universe from baryon-symmetric to baryon-asymmetric requires a violation of $CP$ that distinguishes matter from antimatter.  So the searches for small $CP$ violation are well-motivated.

The nontrivial phenomena that would fit your description would be processes that violate $C$ and $T$ but not $P$ (or, just as interesting, $P$ and $T$ but not $C$).  Off the top of my head I cannot think of any such processes.  The role of the $C$- and $P$-violating, mostly-$CP$-conserving weak interaction makes it unlikely that any such process exists.